# Is there a word for "galaxy" that doesn't reference milk?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing fictional stories that are universe-wide, and I feel like the world "galaxy" is too mammal-centric and Milky Way-centric because it involves a reference to milk.

Is there any other way to call a large unit of stars like this?

Examples:

> Shulamit is from a ____ called NGC 7840.
>
> The sun, Betelgeuse and UY Scuti are all located in Milky Way _____.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why "galaxy" has mammal-centric connotations to you. It's the standard word to refer to that particular cosmic structure. I can't think of any other term which would better suit those example sentences.

Your only other option is to create your own words for it - after all, it's a fictional story which may have fictional languages of its own.

Comment: Very few modern readers will know or care that the root "gala" is from the Greek and PIE for "milk.". If you must, though, just use star system or star cluster.

Comment: @Cascabel I think it’s a poorly-explained belief, rather than a mistaken one. The word _galaxy_ itself is etymologically an adjective meaning ‘milky’ (derived from Greek γάλα _gala_ ‘milk’), so in the sense that any word involves a reference to its etymology and origin, _galaxy_ does reference milk. The trouble is that if you need to scour out all etymological references to things that don’t fit your fictitious world, your options will be _very_ limited.

Comment: Galaxy is a brand of chocolate made by the Mars company. It's very milky, almost disgustingly so in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, @JanusBahsJacquet You are absolutely correct...I have to admit that I dismissed it outa hand, something which I need to do better at. The "mammal-centric" thing threw me off.

Comment: If you don't like **galaxy** surely you wouldn't want to say "...located in the Milky Way _________"

Comment: Also, we don't use "both" when mentioning three things, just two.

Comment: Any galaxy, when viewed from the proper vantage point within that galaxy, would be milky in the sense that the Milky Way is milky. So in that sense, "galaxy" is not Milky Way-centric.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson Well "milk" may not be on every planet to name a galaxy after.

Comment: @RuthlessaWeiss Unless you're being very meta and want to avoid all English words (since not every galaxy will have a planet that speaks English), it remains that  every galaxy is milky in the way the Milky Way is milky, so the word "galaxy" is not Milky Way centric (except by virtue of of being English).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always coin your own word or repurpose an existing one. Readers will catch on.

> X is a star in  myriad 7840.

Answer (score 6):

One expression used is "star system":

- [The Milky Way's sibling spiral star system](https://www.syfy.com/syfywire/the-milky-ways-sibling-spiral-star-system)
- > It is well known that the Milky Way star system is a much flattened organization and that the Sun and planets are well inside. — [American Scientist](https://www.americanscientist.org/article/galaxies)

---

Or you could just use "galaxy". The question seems to fall prey to the [etymological fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy). It's really the same as *knowing something by heart*: you don't actually believe that the heart stores knowledge, right?

A lot of etymology comes from stuff that is obscure to us in the modern day, but it's not something that people get caught up on.